# Client-Server architecture?

Tags: c#

I have to create an application that based on repository of something, and when there is new update n the repository do something to the registred user.
something like inverse client-server (as the server open contant the users).
I hope it's clear enough.
the code is written in C# 4.0.
What is the best architecture to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is Duplex messaging.

Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

This enables two way messaging between a client and a server.

Comment: I'm talking about single client and multiple servers. is the dplex messaging OK for that? (i.e. my single "server" do something to the "clients" (but they can't doo anything, they dont even know he do something))

Comment: Yes this is possible, however is it possible for the "client" to be setup as a "server" and have the servers act as clients to the client?

Because that is what it sounds your trying to do.

Duplex messaging is for two way messaging, what your describing is one way messaging server->client, which is the same as client->server

Comment: Your'e right, what i'm trying to do is client-server (but one client with multiple servers), what you suggest?

Comment: That depends on what the client and server is.

Is the client a webform asp.net etc. 

Expand on your question.